# Condense html file, so I can email it

Tags: html, gzip

I want to email an html file, so that the recepients will be able to save it and open it in a browser. However, it's somewhat big so I want to condense it. I don't want to gzip and send, since I don't trust my recepients to gunzip. I can't assume too much on their knowledge.

I noted that http responses are sometimes gzipped, so the browser can gunzip. So I thought there might be a way to send a file so that the browser will know it has to be gunzipped. Any idea?

Another way I thought of is to translate the html file into docx, as it is a condensed format. It can't be hard, since docx is not much more than xml. Does anyone know a simple way to do it? a Perl or Python module could be great.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) How big is (uncompressed) HTML file? 2) Do you send images/graphic in the email **too**? 3) Can you use more "terse" HTML version?

Comment: *"So I thought there might be a way to send a file so that the browser will know it has to be gunzipped."* - the HTTP response header in this case specifies a `Content-Encoding: gzip` so that the client knows that it needs to gunzip the response body. There is no such thing for transferring files in a mail though.

Comment: "since docx is not much more than xml" is a fallacy – docx files are strictly structured ZIP files that contain XML among other things. Either way, opening a docx file would then require the receiver to have e.g. Word.

Comment: 1) The file is about 1 MB, but can get bigger in the future (I need to do this on a constant basis). 2) For now, I can assume there're no images, videos etc. 3) What do you mean "more terse html"? 4) I know docx contains more things. I meant that it can't be hard to translate html to docx, and surely someone thought of it before me. And I can assume the recepients have MsWord.